# box spout two adjacent cells merge

Tags: php, xlsx

How to merge cell in box spout writing excel file.
I have tried cell merge using below code

```
$customTempFolderPath = sys_get_temp_dir();
$writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
$writer->setTempFolder($customTempFolderPath)
->setShouldUseInlineStrings(true)
->openToFile($filePath)
->addRowWithStyle($header, $headerStyle)
->addRowWithStyle($headerRow, $headerRowStyle)
->addRowsWithStyle($dataRows, $defaultStyle)
->addRowWithStyle($lastRow, $headerRowStyle)
->close();
```

Comment: update your tags with `xlsx` also

Comment: Unfortunately, merging cells is not supported yet. All you can do is add empty cells to simulate a merged cell.

Comment: I have already added empty cells but it is not merge cell